# After windows 10 update, cant connect to sql server from program on a shared folder

Tags: windows, sql-server, windows-10, windows-update

After the new windows 10 update (may 10) my program cant connect to the sql server anymore. The executable is on a shared folder on another computer. 
I've tried to run it as administrator, disabled the firewall, but doesnt work.
i googled, found: nothing.

But, when i copy the executable locally, then it works fine as usually.

Thanks for any clue

The program is in VB6 usign SQLCli10. The programas works fine until the update.

Error: Not server/instance found

Comment: Which specific program can't connect? Have you tried connecting with SQL Server Management Studio? What's the exact error that you get?

Comment: Hi Brent, i edited the question

Comment: Does the program reside on a SMBv1 share/fileserver?

Comment: Just a shared folder on windows machine